# Modifying Gerber file

Tags: pcb-design, altium, kicad, pcb-layers, gerber

I am using the X-NUCLEO-NFC02A1 development board for one of my projects. But I want to make a few modifications to that board design. So I tried to download the Gerber file from the [manufacturer's site](https://www.st.com/en/ecosystems/x-nucleo-nfc02a1.html#cad-resources), and make some modifications on that. I tried to do this with KiCad and Altium. However, the only thing I could do was open the Gerber file; I couldn't make any changes.

Is there any way to modify this Gerber file? Basically, what I want to do is make the pad size bigger and make a few changes to its antenna. I suggest you download this file and view it before you answer.

Comment: "Is there anyway to modify this Gerber file?"  Yes.  However, product recommendations are frowned upon on this site.  As I understand it, most solutions are costly.  A quick search on www.eevblog.com came up with a suggestion or two. Question by tec5c on August 26, 2016 titled "Topic: Gerber Editor?" may give you some leads.

Answer (score 2):

There are Gerber editors available, but since you have Altium you can refer to the Altium [documentation](https://www.altium.com/documentation/knowledge-base/altium-designer/gerber-to-pcb) to covert a Gerber file to PCB. It is best to create a PCB instead of editing Gerber files as it is easier to modify.

The summary at the bottom of the Altium documentation is:

> 1. File ► New ► CAM Document
> 2. File ► Import ► Gerber(s)
> 3. File ► Import ► Drill (Browse to drill file)     If you don't have a drill file you can create one by placing a via on a new PcbDoc then
>    export it as NC drill
> 4. Tables ► Layers (assign the layer types)
> 5. Tables ► Layers Order (Confirm the logical & physical Layer order is correct)
> 6. Tables ► Layers Sets (ensure your drill span shows up here)
> 7. Tools ► Netlist ► Extract
> 8. File ► Export ► Export to PCB

Answer (score 1):

There are programs avalible to edit gerber files. A gerber file does not contain net names, you'll need schematics for those. Another problem with doing direct edits is that you will have to do your own DFM, if you put a piece of copper on top of another one and short something, a gerber editor might not warn you.

Viewmate deluxe is a program I have used in the past to do gerber edits, or just check on the gerbers.