# Multiple layout files for the same amplifier in Altium

Tags: layout

There is an amplifier I want to import a layout of the amplifier shown in the link below. I opened the ZIP folder and I have there about 10 files.
I know DRR is drill report.

When I googled rest of the files I see that they are the same by definition.
I know that there is no netlist.

How do I know what files I need to recreate the layout in Altium?

https://www.qorvo.com/products/d/da007871

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The .G** files are Gerber photoplot files used to produced the PC board.  The usual meanings for the file name extensions are:

- .gtl - top copper layer
- .gbl - bottom copper layer
- .gto - top overlay (silkscreen)
- .gbo - bottom overlay
- .gts - top solder mask
- .gtp - top solder paste

.gd1 and .gd2 may be internal layers if this a four layer board.  .txt may be a drill file. Other files may be reports of some sort.  They are all probably plain text files and can be viewed in Notepad or other plain text editor.

There doesn't appear to be a schematic file.  I don't think you can get these into an editable PC board project in Altium.

Comment: See this [thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/674743/modifying-gerber-file/674813#674813) for importing Gerber files in to Altium.